# How to autogenerate columns in WPF DataGrid using reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, system.reflection

I bind my DataGrid to a collection of objects of different types derived from IMyInterface. I need to group the DataGrid by real type of the objects and autogenerate colulmns within each group based on properties of each type, as the types have different properties.

Please help.

I am adding some of my existing code:

XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="False" 
                    Background="White"
                    Foreground="Black">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Padding="10, 0, 10, 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Item(s)"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="DgPendingMessages" ItemsSource="{Binding }" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    IsReadOnly="True" MaxHeight="400">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TheMessage}" Header="Pending Message" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
public class PendingMessage
{
    //public IMyInterface TheMessage { get; set; }
    public string TheMessage { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
}
```

PendingMessage is my model class which contains a string representation of the real Message object and original type of the Message object (to be used to group the DataGrid by it).

The Message object may be of any type derived from IMyInterface.

```
var collectionPendingMessages = new ListCollectionView(PendingMessages);
collectionPendingMessages.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("MessageType"));
DgPendingMessages.ItemsSource = collectionPendingMessages;
```

Instead of a string representations of the real Message objects I want to have something like this:

Type A: 3 items

Column N | Column Z | Column X | Column T

Data     | Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data     | Data

---

Type B: 4 items

Column N | Column S | Column U

Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data

---

Type C: 3 items

Column N | Column Z | Column X | Column T | Column U

Data     | Data     | Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data     | Data     | Data

Data     | Data     | Data     | Data     | Data

Comment: I had this problem before and solved it with custom attributes.  Have you looked into that possibility?

Comment: No, I don't know what that is.

Comment: fair enough.  The other option that you have is to use a template selector.  Did you try that so far?

Comment: Actually, I do know what custom attributes are. I meant, I didn't know how they could be used to solve my problem. Neither have I tried a template selector. To be honest, I am not that experienced in WPF beyond simple DataGrid population.I just don't know how to approach such a problem. I am thinking about generating a separate DataGrid for each type of objects, if I will not find out how to achieve my goal using grouping, which would be nicer.

Comment: If you implement a template selector, it can automatically display the datagrid that is associated with the class.  And each time the underlying class changes, its datagrid gets presented.  Is that of any use to you?

Comment: @Garry Vass I added some code to my original question. Do you think I could achieve this using a template selector? If yes, could you please refer me to some sample, because from what I read, I could not figure out how that would work with grouping... Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think it can be done with templates, but you are the only person who can REALLY find that out.  After looking at your revisions, I think you may need more than one selector.  Template selectors are a piece of cake.  Why not open another question heavily focused on it and see what you get.  I will check through my stuff for anything useful...

Comment: @Garry Vass I created a new question, like you said, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236417/how-to-autogenerate-columns-for-each-group-in-a-grouped-datagrid-using-template

Comment: Super!  I'll check it when I get home.

Comment: I have been able to do this.  It's a bit tricky, but it gives what you want.  So it's confirmed.  At least by me.

Comment: @Garry Vass Yesterday, I saw your answer there, and left a comment. But today there is no answer and no comment. I have no idea what happened...

Comment: I replied to your comment briefly explaining that I would not paste the code for generating types on the fly because it would make the answer too voluminous and unwieldy, but I *did* explain how to do it and suggested that you overlooked that paragraph (or didn't realize the significance of it).  Then I expressed regret that it didn't work for you along with hopes that somebody else would be contributing to provide an answer more suitable for you.  I noted that you were online and assumed you read it.  Then I deleted the answer to encourage others to have a try.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Garry Vass That is a pity that I didn't see the reply... Thank you anyway.

Comment: Here's a cut and paste of the original reply:  The answer uses fixed types because otherwise it would be too voluminous to publish here. I did write that you could generate new types dynamically by using class decorations, it's the logical extension. You probably missed that paragraph. Sorry it didn't work for you, but hopefully someone will be along with a solution that does work for you

Comment: @Garry Vass I didn't mean that the answer would not work for me, I just wanted to clarify it. And I am sorry for your time.

Comment: Maybe you could restore your answer if you still have it and explain how you meant to use type decorations?

Comment: Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8(v=vs.80).aspx and it includes a usage guide.  I use them all the time and they are a great answer to lots of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've grappled with this issue before. If you are basically using XAML for your views, one option that worked for me is to generate the XAML you need dynamically at run time. It feels a little ugly, but it does seem to work.

Here is a code-behind class I have in one of my projects. Hopefully, it's close enough to your problem to help:

```
public partial class SetupPanel : UserControl
{
    public SetupPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        AddParticipantGridViewColumns();
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }

    public void AddParticipantGridViewColumns()
    {
        ...
        for (var blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < blockColumnCount; blockIndex++)
        {
            var column = BuildParticipantGridViewColumn(blockIndex);
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }

    private DataGridTemplateColumn BuildParticipantGridViewColumn(int blockIndex)
    {
        var columnXaml = string.Format(@"
            <DataGridTemplateColumn
                xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
                xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
                Header=""Block {1}"">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text=""{{Binding BlockViewModels[{0}].ConditionLabel}}""
                                   Foreground=""{{Binding BlockViewModels[{0}].TextBrush}}"" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>",
            blockIndex, blockIndex + 1);
        var column = (DataGridTemplateColumn)XamlReader.Parse(columnXaml);
        return column;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Reading your question again, it's possible that all you would need to do is use `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` for your DataGrid. However, this will only work if you don't want to customize the look of your columns.

---

**Update 2**

Looking at your updated question, it looks like maybe all you really need to do is put your messages into [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) objects, which allow you to build up columns and populate with data dynamically at runtime. Then you can either use AutoGenerateColumns or, if you need more customization, use XAML generation (as I posted above) to add the columns to the DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some things are not clear for me yet, e.g. what BlockViewModel is, and where blockColumnCount comes from, and also how all this works with grouping by type...

Comment: Are you familiar with the MVVM pattern? The view models are a result of using that pattern. However, you can still use the structure of what I've done even if you have a totally different type of project. I would suggest writing up your DataGrid in XAML with hard-coded columns. Then, once you figure out how you want your columns specified, replace my `columnXaml` string with your XAML, replace the static bindings with dynamic stuff, and you should be good to go. (Note: you will need to remove your temporary XAML columns.)

Comment: Unfortunately, because my source collection contains objects as IMyIngterface, they are understood as such, and because the interface contains nothing useful, being just a label interface, with autogenerated columns the rows are empty. And I don't use MVVM.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with some more details about your interface and how you hope to obtain your DataGrid column information? In general, it helps to post some code, even if it doesn't work. Just so we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: The interface is just empty, it is a marker interface. I have to leave now, I may post more information tomorrow, if needed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32179/discussion-between-david-shochet-and-danm)